# Call a javascript function from the activity?

Tags: javascript, android, dom, webview

How can I call a function in a HTML doc that is loaded into a webView with a button that is in my activity?  ie: An ImageButton (called: bookBtn) is in the title bar of the activity.  When it is pressed/tapped, I need it to fire a function in the webView DOM - It basically loads a new HTML doc into the DOM implementing a slide-in effect.

I found plenty of documentation on how to do this from the webView to the activity but not the other way around.  Google says it [can be done](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/using-webviews.html) but there really isnt any examples.  I tried to tweek the example code they show [here](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java) but I cant get it to work.  Thank for any input.

Below is the function w/in the HTML doc that is loaded into the webView, mWebView:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        function loadTOC(){$.mobile.changePage("docs/1-1.html", "slideup");
        };
    });
</script>
```

...and w/in my main activity, I tried this as per Google docs but doesn't work:

```
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bookBtn);
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:loadTOC");
            }
        });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

There are at least two problems in the code:

1) The javascript URL doesn't invoke the loadTOC function, it just references it. What you want is:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:loadTOC()");
```

2) The `loadTOC` function isn't globally visible AFAIK, so the javascript URL won't be able to access it.

You should also make sure that JavaScript is enabled as no-good-at-coding suggests.

Comment: Thnk - I was missing the round brackets but that wasnt the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see in here so I'm going to add that you ought to make sure you have

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);.
```

in your Android code